# ASP.NET textbox cssClass gets overrwritten in GridView ItemTemplate after rendering

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox, itemtemplate, templatefield

I have a textbox inside a TemplateField column for a gridview. When I set the cssClass property for the textbox, it gets overwritten by a "textBox" class in the rendered web page. Is this normal behavior? 
(.NET 3.5)

As a workaround I added a 'style' attribute.

Comment: Do you have a 'textBox' class explicitly defined in your css?

Comment: I found it in the default.skin file for asp:textbox entry. Now I know why it's there but why is it overriding my cssClass for that specific textbox? Even with 'EnableTheming' turned off for the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that SkinId has precedance over CssClass:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1469529.aspx/1